# Use HttpService with Gemini Web

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-virgo, eclipse-gemini, httpservice

How can i use OSGi HTTPService in Gemini Web.

Best Regards,
Keshav

Answer (score 0):

the plugin **org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet** provides a servlet implementation that creates a HTTPService, which when registered with root context "/" and with url pattern "/*"  redirects all the requests to HttpService via Proxy Servlet.

Also you can use the plugin **org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry** to create entries for HTTPService via extension points.

Best Regards,
Keshav